# Make sure that the class defined in this code file matches the 'inherits' attribute 3

Tags: c#, asp.net, sitecore

I recently inherited another vendor's project and I am trying to turn it into a usable Visual Studio 2010 solution.

The error I'm currently running into is:

> Make sure that the class defined in this code file matches the
>   'inherits' attribute, and that it extends the correct base class (e.g.
>   Page or UserControl).

I have found this question posed several other times, but none of the solutions seem to work in this case.  Below is the code in question:

~/layouts/Header.ascx.cs

```
using System;
using Client._Classes.Global;
using Client._Classes.Helpers;
using Client._Classes.Utilities;

namespace Layouts.layouts_Header
{

    public partial class layouts_Header : BaseControl
    {
        private void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void lnkSignIn_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Session["CurrentPageURL"] = Sitecore.Context.RawUrl;
            Response.Redirect("/en/Community/Register.aspx");
        }

        protected void btnSearchSubmit_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string redirectURL = "/en/Search%20Results.aspx?cx=005917832522243245879:kpcudcaotoo&cof=FORID:11&ie=UTF-8&q=" + txtSearchQueryStr.Text;

            Response.Redirect(redirectURL);
        }

    }

}
```

~/layouts/Header.ascx

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="~/layouts/Header.ascx.cs" Inherits="Layouts.layouts_Header.layouts_Header" %>
```

BaseControl.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Globalization;

using Sitecore.Data.Items;
using Sitecore.Diagnostics;
using Sitecore.Web;
using Sitecore.SharedSource.Data.Comparers.ItemComparers;
using Sitecore.Data.Fields;
using Sitecore.SharedSource.Searcher;
using Sitecore.SharedSource.Searcher.Parameters;
using Sitecore.SharedSource.Searcher.Utilities;
using Sitecore.Collections;

using Client._Classes.Utilities;
using Client._Classes.Helpers;
using Client._Classes.Global;

namespace Client._Classes.Global
{
    public class BaseControl : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

It should be noted that several other .ascx controls inherit from BaseControl as well, and there does not appear to be any issues.

Comment: Is this the only control that fails or does the page just fail because this is loading first?

Comment: when do you get this error? during building or when rendering the page?

Comment: this is the only control that fails.  i receive this error when building the solution.

Comment: All examples I've found with this error have the solution to change CodeFile to CodeBehind in the ascx. It might be worth checking if the other controls have a CodeBehind rather than CodeFile?

Comment: Thanks for the idea, however changing CodeFile to CodeBehind results in the following error:
'Layouts.layouts_Header.layouts_Header'

It appears that there are atleast a dozen controls in this project, and all appear to be functioning normally using CodeBehind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the solution provided to me contained a folder structure as such:

> /temp/installation_history/681FBB6D58774C7D96B37D1353B7441E/layouts

which contained copies of Header.ascx and Header.ascx.cs.  I discovered these files when I excluded the actual copies from Header.ascx and Header.ascx.cs from my project.

Once I removed the temp folder and all of its contents, the solution compiled.  Thanks everyone for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is that your namespace name ends with your class name:

```
namespace Layouts.layouts_Header
{
    public partial class layouts_Header // * snip *
```

Try removing the `layouts_Header` part from your namespace and then change the value of the `Inherits` attribute to `Layouts.layouts_Header`

Comment: Eric Lippert has a nice series explaining more about what Ruud is suggesting: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/03/09/do-not-name-a-class-the-same-as-its-namespace-part-one.aspx

Comment: Thanks Ruud and Joe.  I will be correcting these namespaces as I refactor the code.